# "Ratio" vs "Proportion"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

As you know, ["ratio"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/ratio) is a relationship between two groups or amounts that expresses how much bigger one is than the other. While ["proportion"](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/proportion) is the number or amount of a group or part of something when compared to the whole.

I know it may sound quite distinguishable to you native speakers, but it is somehow vague to me as a non-native individual. I wonder if you do me a favor and let me know what structure is used in each sentence below:

> 1. Everyone can spend money ........ his/her income.

a. in proportion to 
b. in ratio of

> 2. The .......... of men to women in the conference was 10 to 1.

a. proportion 
b. ratio

> 3. The income you earn in this job is in direct ........... to the effort you put in.

a. proportion 
b. ratio

> 4. His feet are small in .......... to his weight.

a. proportion 
b. ratio

Answer (score 1):

As a non-native speaker of English, these sentences sound okay to me (slightly different than yours):

> 1. Not everyone spends money **in proportion to** their income.
> 2. **The ratio of men to women** at the conference was 10 to 1.
> 3. The money you earn is **in direct proportion to** the effort you put in.
> 4. His feet are small **in proportion to** his height.

Comment: As a non-native speaker too, I have to note that _proportion_ and _ratio_ are often countable nouns, so articles are required then.

Comment: @MvLog Not here, though, since we aren't talking about specific proportions. *In (direct) proportion to* is pretty much an established phrase.

Comment: Sure, but _ratio_ is always a countable noun. _Proportion_ is countable when it means "part" — _A propotion of XXX has increased..._